# How can I ignore scala library while sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using `sbt` to build my `scala` project.

This is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "My Spark App"
version := "1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.0" % "provided"
```

I am running `sbt assembly` to create an assembly jar, but I found a scala directory containing scala library class codes.

Is it possible to take scala library as a **provided** dependency, since the run-time environment already contains scala?

Answer (score 10):

From [docs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), this might help

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```